# tezos-node synchronized carthagenet chain too slow

Tags: node

I am using tezos-node to synchronize carthagenet chain. My config file is

```
{ "data-dir": "/data/install/tezos/node-data",
  "rpc": { "listen-addrs": [ "0.0.0.0:20340" ] },
  "p2p":
    { "bootstrap-peers": [ "boot.tzbeta.net" ], "listen-addr": "[::]:20339",
      "limits":
        { "connection-timeout": 10, "max-download-speed": 102400,
          "max-upload-speed": 102400, "max_known_points": [ 400, 300 ],
          "max_known_peer_ids": [ 400, 300 ] } },
  "log": { "output": "/data/install/tezos/Log/tezos-node.log" },
  "network":
    { "genesis":
        { "timestamp": "2019-11-28T13:02:13Z",
          "block": "BLockGenesisGenesisGenesisGenesisGenesisd6f5afWyME7",
          "protocol": "PtYuensgYBb3G3x1hLLbCmcav8ue8Kyd2khADcL5LsT5R1hcXex" },
      "chain_name": "TEZOS_ALPHANET_CARTHAGE_2019-11-28T13:02:13Z",
      "sandboxed_chain_name": "SANDBOXED_TEZOS",
      "default_bootstrap_peers":
        [ "tezaria.com", "34.76.169.218", "34.90.24.160",
          "carthagenet.kaml.fr", "104.248.136.94" ] } }
```

the latest log is

```
Apr  2 14:14:06 - p2p.maintenance: Too few connections (0)
Apr  2 14:14:11 - p2p.maintenance: Too few connections (0)
Apr  2 14:14:16 - p2p.maintenance: Too few connections (0)
Apr  2 14:14:22 - p2p.maintenance: Too few connections (0)
Apr  2 14:14:27 - p2p.maintenance: Too few connections (0)
Apr  2 14:14:32 - p2p.maintenance: Too few connections (0)
Apr  2 14:14:37 - p2p.maintenance: Too few connections (0)
Apr  2 14:14:42 - p2p.maintenance: Too few connections (0)
Apr  2 14:14:47 - p2p.maintenance: Too few connections (0)
Apr  2 14:14:52 - p2p.maintenance: Too few connections (0)
Apr  2 14:14:57 - p2p.maintenance: Too few connections (0)
```

It seems to be disable connect to p2p network.

And, where is carthagenet snpshot, like https://github.com/Phlogi/tezos-snapshots?

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between "mainnet" and "carthagenet". The former, "mainnet", is currently what is running across the entire Tezos network.  "carthagenet" is a TESTING/DEVELOPMENT network which is completely isolated from mainnet. Are you running the correct software and connecting to the correct network?

Answer (score 1):

Carthagenet uses different bootstrap peers ( source: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/bin_node/node_config_file.ml#L121 )

you can also just omit the bootstrap peers from the config file and it will use the hardcoded default ones.

Snapshots are available here:

https://snapshots.tulip.tools/#/

Comment: I am sure that my config is correct. After imported snapshot, I restart my node, and I still cannot connect to other peers. And then I clear bootstrap node config, it doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: does it start syncing if you start it without any config file at all? because if not that is most likely a networking issue

Comment: yes, I think the node synchronize mainnet block

Comment: ah! I think i understand your problem...If you are on master branch, try running the node with `--network carthagenet`, we used to have multiple branches for each network, now everything is in one branch/node and users not running on mainnet should specify the network with this flag. hope it works with that

Comment: also, i am not sure about your use case and running tezos like this is perfectly fine, however do look at https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/teztool, maybe that is easier for you.

Comment: are there some way that doesn't use docker?

Comment: yes, you can compile it from source but thats beyond the cope of this question.